Why does Spring 5 give me 403/404 for the from login
I upgrading an app from Spring Security 3.2 to 5.8.  Following Spring Security XML I get a 403 if I don't have
<security:http security="none" pattern="/dologin" />

Otherwise I get a 404
    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        login-processing-url="/dologin"
        default-target-url="/secure/user/dashboard"
        always-use-default-target='true'
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" />

DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /dologin
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/dologin
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl - Responding with 403 status code
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext


you need to know WHY you are getting 403, set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error. After that paste the error into question please.

It was the CSRF token.  You can put an answer or I can.

Show your custom login page. Did you add a hidden field with CSRF token?

Needed to disable CSRF <security:csrf disabled="true" />

You should not disable CSRF, it is not secure. You should instead send the CSRF token.
